# How to select only element inside the div through css

Tags: html, css

In my application i need to extract the data which is inside the div element and to exclude the text which is inside the paragraph element which is also a child of div element.

The snippet looks like

```
<div class ="hrt">
  This is div text
   <p>This is paragraph text</p>
</div>
```

Through Css Selector i want to retreive the div text : 
In above case i want my solution to be : **This is div text**

Comment: What do you mean "retrieve the div text": why do you want to return content with CSS ? Maybe you mean "targetting the direct child node of an element" ?

Comment: by javascript or something else?

Answer (score 1):

**You can't target text nodes with CSS. You must wrap them with an element (span or whatever).**

*If you can't modify your HTML content, you'll need some JS.*

Leave a comment if you need help to achieve this with JS.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can simply apply `display: none` to the child element.

```css
.hrt {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.hrt p {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class ="hrt">
  This is div text
   <p>This is paragraph text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this:

```
 .hrt {
     font-weight: bold;
 }

 .hrt>* {
     font-weight: initial;
 }
```

That way, your style will affect only elements content and not its children.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

**Option one**

Wrap the first text in an element and style that:

```css
.hrt>p:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="hrt">
  <p>This is div text</p>
  <p>This is paragraph text</p>
</div>
```

**Option two**

First style the text in the div, than overwrite the text in the paragraph:

```css
.hrt {
  font-weight: 900;
}
.hrt p {
  font-weight: 100;
}
/* or to target all elements
.hrt * {
  font-weight: 100;
}
*/
```

```html
<div class ="hrt">
   This is div text
   <p>This is paragraph text</p>
</div>
```